# How to in rmarkdown `r print(df$`my variable` )`

Tags: r, datatable, r-markdown

When a variable name in `data.table` is not a single word but two, you can access it using reverse quotes like df$`Transaction Date` .

However the same reverse quotes are used for `rmarkdown` for online execution.
So a line like below will not compile in `rmarkdown`:

```
# Chapter 1: Transaction dates
Transactions started on  `r df$`Transaction Date` %>% min`.
```

How to I do it?

PS. to have reproducible example, you can do this:

```
 names(cars)[1] <- "car speed".
```

Then try printing the min of it in Rmarkdown using `r min(cars$`car speed`)`

Comment: How about `df[["Transaction Date"]]`?

Comment: This is a [known issue with `knitr`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1099). At this point, it does not seem like there are plans to fix it. Set up your code to use quotes instead, as in the comment above.

Comment: This works in this particular case. Thank you.  I will need to check if it works though in more tricky cases

Comment: For column names, there's always a way to use them as strings. The real issue would be if you were giving objects non-standard names---but you really shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In interim, my workaround is to create a function everywhere I need to call a two-word variable name:

```
of <- function (x, col)  {
  return(x[, col, with=F]) 
}
```

Then run

```
 # Chapter 1: Transaction dates
 Transactions started on  `r df  %>% of("Transaction Date") %>% lapply(min)`.
```

Comment: If you want a vector of a single columnyou can use `dplyr::pull`, `df %>% pull("Transaction Date")`, or even if you're just using `magrittr` you can use `extract2`, `df %>% extract2("Transaction Date")`. (And then you could use `%>% min` instead of `%>% lapply(min)`. If you want a one-column data frame/table, you can use `dplyr::select`. Not sure that a new custom function adds anything, unless you're thinking of it as a `data.table` alias for `select` with more limited options.